# Programming with Twisted based on sockets FD

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, reactor

I'm trying to write a TCP server (reactor based) which works as follows:

- Server accepts connections
- Server receives from each connection a specific identifier, which it maps directly to the connection's FD
- Server monitors (Asynchronously) these specific IDs (It can be ids of specific files, or records in a DB)
- When a specific ID is changed, the server sends a message to the specific client which is mapped to the ID

I didn't see anything like that in twisted. Each connection in twisted, calls "protocol.dataReceived(data)" directly with no mentions of the FD, so it doesn't know from which socket the data was received.

Now I'm probably missing something, so the **question** is
Is there anyway to write this cleanly using Twisted? Writing a server behavior based on FDs? and If twisted doesn't have this functionality what do you suggest using?